# When saving certain Business Process Flows: "An error has occurred. Try this action again"

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am trying to edit a Business Process Flow in CRM Online/Dynamics 365. When I save the BPF, the following error shows:

> An error has occurred. Try this action again. If the problem
>   continues, check the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Community for solutions or
>   contact your organization's Microsoft Dynamics CRM Administrator.
>   Finally, you can contact Microsoft Support

The button for downloading logs is greyed out.

This error shows up even if I just open up the BPF and try to save it without adding or changing any fields.

This issue occurs for all BPFs that came with the system out of the box. Any BPFs created at a later stage can be edited without any problem. The base language of my organization is not English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved in the following way:

1. Create a solution containing the problematic workflows.
2. Export the solution.
3. Open the .xaml files and do a search/replace for `LanguageCode="0"` with `LanguageCode="1033"`
4. Re-import the solution.